# Hartshorne II Prop 2.6

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Prop 2.6 constructed a continuous map $X$ to $t(X)$, I cannot verify that it is a homeomorphism. I try to show any open set $U$ is mapped to $t(X)\setminus t(X\setminus U)$. To show it is surjective, let $K$ be an irreducible closed subset intersecting $U$. I have to show it is the closure of some point in $U$, but why?

Comment: Have a look at better books (for example the one by Görtz-Wedhorn), there you find more details.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in Prop 3.23.

Comment: But in Hartshorne's book the map was defined for any topological space. I wonder if he forgot to add the condition that X is the underlying space of some scheme?

Comment: A late but useful comment: Hartshorne seems to set it up correctly.  There is always a map $X\to t(X)$, the space of nonempty irreducible closed subsets.  It's injective when $X$ is $T_0$, it's surjective when $X$ is sober, and it's a homeomorphism when $X$ is both.  I believe that any such space (sober and $T_0$) is homeomorphic to the underlying space of a scheme.